# FormData not posting data to php backend script

Tags: php, jquery

I have this form

```
<form id="home"  class="validate-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <!-- Form Item -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>How much money do you need? (USD)</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">USD</div>
                                    <input id="moneyAmount" type="number" name="amount" class="form-control slider-control input-lg" value="100000" min="10000" max="1000000" data-slider="#moneySlider" required>
                                </div>
                                <div id="moneySlider" class="form-slider" data-input="#moneyAmount" data-min="10000" data-max="1000000" data-value="100000"></div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Form Item -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>How long? (months)</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input id="monthNumber" type="number" name="months" class="form-control slider-control input-lg" value="10" min="6" max="12" data-slider="#monthSlider" required>
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">months</div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="monthSlider" class="form-slider"  data-input="#monthNumber" data-min="6" data-max="12" data-value="10"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Telephone Number</label>
                                <!-- Radio -->
                                <input type="number" name="telephone" class="form-control" required/>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Form Item -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>3 Months Bank or Paypal </label>
                                <!-- Radio -->
                                <input type="file" name="statements" class="ml btn btn-primary btn-lg" /><span>Upload</span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Form Item -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Monthly repayment</label>
                                <span id="formResult" class="form-total">USD<span>262.99</span></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-submit">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn-submit btn-lg"><span>Send a request!</span></button>
                            </div>
</form>
```

that i am using to post a file and some data via formData. This is the jquery code

```
$( "#home" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/home.php',  
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    return false;

});
```

and finally the php script

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");


$rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");

return print_r($rawData);
?>
```

On the client side, the `console.log(data)` is empty. Why am i not able to get the posted data?.

Comment: there is no `action_url` in your form

Comment: `action_url` is not required as the data is posted using ajax

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `$_FILES`? Either way, try with that. I don't think `php://input` is ment to be used with `multipart/form-data` uploads.

Comment: did u check the console for whats being posted ?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson That was the issue  `I don't think php://input is ment to be used with multipart/form-data uploads` i can get the values using `$_POST['amount']` for instance.

Comment: There's no reason to use `php://input` instead of the super globals unless for special cases (like working with `$_PUT` or you need to stream the input or similar). For "standard" form inputs, the super globals tend to do the trick.

Comment: ^ I meant, if you're working with PUT-requests (there is no such thing as `$_PUT`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `php://input` allows you to read raw POST data but
`php://input` does not work when `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
for detailed info :
http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

echo '<pre>'l
// for upload data
print_r($_FILES);
echo '<br>';
// for posted data
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Form which you are sending through ajax is not correct.

You can give your whole form to FormData() for processing

```
var form = $('#home')[0]; // You need to use standard javascript object here
var formData = new FormData(form);
```

use this `formData` to send with ajax

Comment: Don't just post links as answers. If the link explains the issue, include the conclusion and the fix in your answer. Links change, posts gets deleted etc. Then this answer will be useless.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery supported get all form data with function [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

In your code use

```
$( "#home" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var formData = $( "#home" ).serialize();
     $.ajax({
       url: 'http://example.com/home.php',  
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       async: true,
       success: function (data) {
       console.log(data)
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  });
});
```

In PHP use `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to get all input without `file` type. With file type you can read [PHP Upload File](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Comment: That's not using `FormData` (which you need to do if you want to upload files using ajax). The OP has a `<input type="file" />` in the form.